# Magento $product->save() is slower part of script

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, save, script

In my **Magento 1.9.1** I am updating the inventory via script. Via this script I update almost 19K products. 
I have used `$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);` to fetch the records and `$product->save()`  to save the products records. But `$product->save()` is the slowest part of the script.
Please let me what is the other method in Magento to fix this issue.

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
try {

    $stockItem->setStockData(array('is_in_stock' => $isinstock, 'qty' => $quantity));
    $weight_pro = ($length * $width * $height) / 166;
    if ($weight_pro < $weight) {
        $stockItem->setWeight($weight);
    } else {
        $stockItem->setWeight($weight_pro);
    }
    $stockItem->save();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log('Failed for stockupdate  ' . $e);
}
```

Comment: maybe database is the bottleneck

Comment: @stetoc what do you mean by bottleneck. I have monitor the mysql log there is no error. also no more CPU usage. sometimes its working sometimes its stop in between the execution.

Comment: by bottleneck I mean that maybe db is just slow and that's why it's slowing down

Comment: please add your full code here so that myself or others can help you in optimzation of code.

Comment: No @stetoc if I run by normal php query  the execution is perfect and fast but whenever I used this `product->save()` script taking too much  time and break in bettween the execution,

Comment: @PradeepSanku I have added the code block save code is run for the all products.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try saving with attribute instead of saving all the product ?

```
$product->setData('attribute','value');
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'attribute');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you save product then every time load product model and save product data so it will take to much time 
i sugest to run custom mysql query to update your weight.

For ex:

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

$weight_pro = ($length * $width * $height) / 166;
if ($weight_pro < $weight) {
    $query = "UPDATE m_catalog_product_entity_varchar SET value = '".$weight."' WHERE attribute_id = '89' AND entity_id = '".$ProductId."'";
    $updateStock = $writeConnection->query($query);
} else {
    $stockItem->setWeight($weight_pro);
    $query = "UPDATE m_catalog_product_entity_varchar SET value = '".$weight_pro."' WHERE attribute_id = '89' AND entity_id = '".$ProductId."'";
    $updateStock = $writeConnection->query($query);
}
```

89 is your product attribute id. when you edit arrtibute then you can show attribute is on url. https://prnt.sc/ks0twq

Answer (score 0):

You must disable the indexation on save of product.
Or you try the saveAttribute.

Comment: Its already set to "Manual Update".